# Disable interchange functionality in drag and drop sortable list

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Please find link as below:

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Here has 2 block where we can drag the div one block to another also interchange itself.

But for my application I want to disable interchange functionality.

which parameter is required for disable interchange itself?

Comment: This is done with the connectWith option of the plugin, if you dont provide anything it is false by default anyway.

Comment: if you don't want each list sortable, don't use sortable plugin and just use draggable and droppable

Comment: @ryadavilli: Hey, "Div" should be drag with one block(orange border) to another(gray border). but not interchange itself(orange border div with orange border div),

I think you got my point and sory for my english

Comment: @charlietfl: can we disable sortable for that example?

Comment: no..you want lists to connect... not to be sortable, so there is no sense using a sortable plugin

Answer (score 0):

I tried a mix of various jquery sortable events and methods, but found no solution to enact what are you asking for.

It is like asking asking the iPhone5 to restricts it camera back to 3.2MP. If you want that functionality, then simply use iPhone 3 :P

So look at the draggable and droppable plugins, and you will get what you want.